# UI Prompt repeatedly popping up in spreadsheet, how can I make it pop up only once?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm not sure what I am missing, but the `ui.prompt` in `function checkDate(row)` keeps popping up. I only want it to pop up once. What I think is the problem is, is that `return (row[7].getFullYear() === formatteddate);` is retrieving `var formatteddate` repeatedly for each row.

A little background on the script, a date gets inputted through a `ui.prompt`, the year is taken from that date, and placed as `var formatteddate` in number format.

`function checkDate(row)`, checks all the rows for the year `var formatteddate` in column 7.

`function filterRows()`, takes the information from checkdate and filters the rows.

The script duplicating and deleting the sheet is just part of my testing so I don't need to always duplicate my data before testing the script. Taking the year out of date is also just part of my testing/building process.

If you are to test the script, please create two sheets, 'Master Log' and 'Copy of Master Log'. In 'Master Log' Starting from row 2, place some dates down column H (column 7). Ideally some 2016 and 2017 dates. To see the filtering in action. 'Copy of Master Log' will be deleted/created on each run.

How do I create that separation in `function checkDate(row)`, so that `var formatteddate` is only being retrieved once, by `return (row[7].getFullYear() === formatteddate);`?

Thank you! =)

```
    function checkDate(row) {

      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      var prompt = ui.prompt('Start Date', 'Enter a date in m/d/y format', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
      var date = new Date(prompt.getResponseText());
      var formatteddate = Number(Utilities.formatDate(date, "PST", "yyyy"));
      Logger.log(date);
      Logger.log(formatteddate);

      return (row[7].getFullYear() === formatteddate);  // Check column H
      Logger.log(row[7].getFullYear() === formatteddate)
      }

    function filterRows() {

      var Spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet1 = Spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Copy of Master Log');
      var sheet2 = Spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Master Log');

      Spreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheet1);
      Spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(sheet2);
      Spreadsheet.duplicateActiveSheet();

      var headers = 1; // # rows to skip
      var sheet = Spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Copy of Master Log');
      var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
      var headerData = data.splice(0,headers); // Skip header rows
      var filteredData = data.filter( checkDate );
      var outputData = headerData.concat(filteredData);  // Put headers back
      Logger.log(filteredData)

      sheet.clearContents();  // Clear content, keep format

      // Save filtered values
      sheet.getRange(1, 1, outputData.length, outputData[0].length).setValues(outputData); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Array.fliter(function) invokes the function for each element of the array. 
So in your code, the function checkDate was invoked from each element of the data (or for each row in your sheet).

The below modified code asks the user to enter the filter criteria once and updates the global variable with the same. So your function checkDate can access the said variable and not invoke user prompt for each row.

PS: Anything after a return statement is not executed, so your log after the return statement of checkDate(row) function was not being executed. This made you believe that this

```
 return (row[7].getFullYear() === globalFormattedDate);
```

Was the culprit in your code.

```
var globalFormattedDate    //global declaration of the variable

function getFilterDate(){
 var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      var prompt = ui.prompt('Start Date', 'Enter a date in m/d/y format', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
      var date = new Date(prompt.getResponseText());
      var formatteddate = Number(Utilities.formatDate(date, "PST", "yyyy"));
      Logger.log(date);
      Logger.log(formatteddate);
      globalFormattedDate  = fomatteddate  // setting your global variable value

}

function checkDate(row) {


      Logger.log(row[7].getFullYear() === globalFormattedDate) // Moved from after the return statement
      return (row[7].getFullYear() === globalFormattedDate);  // Check column H
      // Anything here wont be excuted return is the last line of excute in a function. 
      }

    function filterRows() {

      var Spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet1 = Spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Copy of Master Log');
      var sheet2 = Spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Master Log');

      Spreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheet1);
      Spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(sheet2);
      Spreadsheet.duplicateActiveSheet();

      var headers = 1; // # rows to skip
      var sheet = Spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Copy of Master Log');
      var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
      var headerData = data.splice(0,headers); // Skip header rows
      getFilterDate()  // This sets the globalFormattedDate to be used by checkdate
      var filteredData = data.filter( checkDate );
      var outputData = headerData.concat(filteredData);  // Put headers back
      Logger.log(filteredData)

      sheet.clearContents();  // Clear content, keep format

      // Save filtered values
      sheet.getRange(1, 1, outputData.length, outputData[0].length).setValues(outputData); 
    }
```